# jQuery: When using .load() to load php file, cause XHR finished loading to increase exponentially with every load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, performance

I am having a problem where by im using .load() to load my php page into the div when ever i press the navbar or link. However I have realised that now after multiple presses of the link and navbar, the "XHR finished loading" increases exponentially and it seems that the same php file gets called more than once.

Part of my javascript code which i put in a general javascript file called general.js which is also inserted to every other php file as it seems that if I dont insert into my php file which require part of my javascript code it would not run

Part  of this code loads a php file into a div . Whenever any of the navbar becomes click, it loads the php content however the load request load the file multiple times and this increases with the number of clicks.

```
$(".uk-navbar-nav").click(function(){

    if($("#subnav_1").hasClass("uk-active")){
      $("#welcome_tab").load("z_admin_welcome/welcome_admin.php");
      console.log("nav1");
  }
    else if($("#subnav_2").hasClass("uk-active")){
      $("#message_tab").load("z_admin/message_admin.php");
      console.log("nav2");
  }

  else if($("#subnav_3").hasClass("uk-active")){
        $("#Face_tab").load("z_admin_face/face_admin.php");
        console.log("nav3");
      }

  else if($("#subnav_4").hasClass("uk-active")){
        $("#QR_tab").load("z_admin/QR_admin.php");

        console.log("nav4");
    }
});
```

This is an example file of what is being loaded into the div (welcome_admin.php)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <!-- css styling is only on admin.php -->
 <!-- br break new line -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="uikit/js/uikit.min.js"></script> <!-- insert this as failing to do so cause it not to work -->

 </head>

 <body>

    <h3> Status </h3>
    <hr> 

    <div class="uk-margin">
        <div data-uk-button-radio data-uk-switcher="{connect: '#radio_status'}" id="welcome_radio_but">
            <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-10 radio_welcome" id="radio_but_1">Available</button>
            <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-10 radio_welcome" id="radio_but_2">Away</button>
            <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-10 radio_welcome" id="radio_but_3">Busy</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul id="radio_status" class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
        <li class="uk-active uk-panel-box uk-width-1-3" aria-hidden="false" id="radio_display_1">Please knock before entering</li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" class="uk-panel-box uk-width-1-3" id="radio_display_2"></li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" class="uk-panel-box uk-width-1-3" id="radio_display_3">Do Not Disturb,please email me</li>

    </ul>


 </body>

 </html>
```

[image: This is a screenshot of my issue whereby XHR get called and finished multiple times for the same file being loaded]

This is a screenshot of my issue whereby XHR get called and finished multiple times for the same file being loaded.

So in a gist,  the issue with being this is that php files gets called multiple time and eventually slowdown/crash the browser.

Would like to know:

1. Should i stop attaching one general javascript to all my external php files that i would load into? (split up the functions and save to multiple different js file? )
2. Any other solution?

   Thank you any help/suggestion

> **Update 1: Where `.uk-navbar-nav` is being placed, this is the main page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head> <!--inseart script here -->
            <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="uikit/css/uikit.gradient.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="uikit/css/components/sticky.gradient.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="uikit/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="uikit/js/components/sticky.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body onload="body_load()">


    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-top"> <!--top center margin overall -->


    <h1 class="uk-heading-large uk-panel-title uk-panel-box uk-icon-rebel"> This is the Main Page </h1>

    <!-- simpler header line stop here -->
    <div data-uk-sticky="{animation: uk-animation-slide-top}">
        <nav class="uk-navbar">
          <!-- Navigation tab bars -->
             <ul class="uk-navbar-nav" data-uk-switcher="{connect:'#subnav-pill-content-1'}">
              <li class="uk-active" id="subnav_1" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-medium uk-icon-home"></i> Welcome</a></li>
              <li aria-expanded="false" id="subnav_2" class=""><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-medium uk-icon-envelope"></i> Message</a></li>
              <li aria-expanded="false" id="subnav_3" class=""><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-medium uk-icon-camera"></i> Facial Recognition</a></li>
              <li aria-expanded="false" id="subnav_4" class=""><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-medium uk-icon-qrcode"></i> QR Code</a></li>
              <li aria-expanded="false" id="subnav_5" class=""><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-medium uk-icon-gears"></i> Settings</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>  
            <ul id="subnav-pill-content-1" class="uk-switcher">
              <!--welcome page -->
              <li class="uk-active" aria-hidden="false" id="welcome_tab" value=""></li>

              <!--Message -->
              <li aria-hidden="true" id="message_tab" class=""></li>

              <!--Facial Recognition -->
              <li aria-hidden="true" id="Face_tab" class=""></li>

              <!--QR Code -->
              <li aria-hidden="true"  id="QR_tab" class=""></li>

              <!--Settings Code -->
              <li aria-hidden="true"  id="settings_tab" class=""></li>
            </ul> 
        <!-- end of navigation tab bar -->

        </div>


     </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should show us the HTML code where is placed `.uk-navbar-nav`.

Comment: Most likely you are re-loading the same script and adding new event handlers each time it loads...causing more and more requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if your `welcome_admin.php` is loaded only via jQuery's `load` function, it should not have an entire HTML code (`html`, `head`, `body` tags, etc). And it should be not loading your `general.js` file.

Try to change it only for the content that should be loaded into the div, e.g:

```
<h3> Status </h3>
<hr>

<div class="uk-margin">
  <div data-uk-button-radio data-uk-switcher="{connect: '#radio_status'}" id="welcome_radio_but">
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-10 radio_welcome" id="radio_but_1">Available</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-10 radio_welcome" id="radio_but_2">Away</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-10 radio_welcome" id="radio_but_3">Busy</button>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="radio_status" class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
  <li class="uk-active uk-panel-box uk-width-1-3" aria-hidden="false" id="radio_display_1">Please knock before entering</li>
  <li aria-hidden="true" class="uk-panel-box uk-width-1-3" id="radio_display_2"></li>
  <li aria-hidden="true" class="uk-panel-box uk-width-1-3" id="radio_display_3">Do Not Disturb,please email me</li>
</ul>
```

This will prevent your `general.js` file being loaded many times, and then, adding new event handlers to your `uk-navbar-nav` each time your a new page is loaded by jQuery.

Another thing is: the way you're doing the event delegation is not really cool. You should be doing:

```
$('.uk-navbar-nav').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  var item = e.target;

  switch (item.id) {
    case 'subnav_1':
      $('#welcome_tab').load('z_admin_welcome/welcome_admin.php');
      break;
    case 'subnav_2':
      $('#message_tab').load('z_admin/message_admin.php');
      break;
    case 'subnav_3':
      $('#Face_tab').load('z_admin_face/face_admin.php');
      break;
    case 'subnav_4':
      $('#QR_tab').load('z_admin/QR_admin.php');
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: for the js file where you placed `var item = e.target` i was thinking of inserting `e.preventDefault(); ` to prevent the bubbling effect?

Comment: Since you're using `li` tags, there is no need for preventing default behavior. But it would be better if in your menu you were using `a` tags inside your `li`tags, so you could use the `href` attribute of it, and then, you could use the `e.preventDefault` method to prevent the default behavior (of redirecting to the other page), and instead, you could use the jQuery's `load` method. e.g `$('.uk-navbar-nav').on('click', 'li a', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $(e.target).load(e.target.href); });`

Comment: @peekaboo if my answer was useful for you, please upvote it by clicking on the arrow, and if it's good enough, mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking on the `V`. Thanks! :)

Comment: i forgot to mention, if i don't include my js function for my say `welcome_admin.php` and edited as per your suggestion, and only include that function in my general js file which will be only loaded on the main page, the `welcome_admin.php` page which require those function would not work..

In this case would you suggest creating separate js file for each page?which will be added to it. Eg: on my  `welcome_admin.php` just above the first line of the div tag, i would insert that individual js file ?

Comment: @peekaboo you could use [jQuery's event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), so your code would start working as soon as you add something to the page. Or you could add each of your code into a wrapper, e.g: `var welcome_tab = { init: function() { /* your code for welcome_tab load here */ };` and so on for the other tabs. And then, you can do something like: `$('#welcome_tab').load('z_ad(...).php').then(welcome_tab.init);`

Answer (score 2):

Calling the same code twice will add 2 event handlers that do the same thing...loading it again will create a third handler and so on

Prevent compounding adding the new click handlers by removing the existing ones using `off()` before you add the new one.

```
$(".uk-navbar-nav").off('click').click(function(){

    // your existing click handler code

});
```

Ideally you would only need this code loaded once if you were to use event delegation

Comment: Although it will probably work, that's a workaround, and they should try to understand why they're adding more than one event handler, since they should be adding only one :)

Comment: Do i seperate my js file and add that line for pages that i dont want to have click function

Comment: @Buzinas that's why I commented about using event delegation

Comment: @Buzinas what do you by adding more event handler? I add event handler for only targeted id div content

Comment: @peekaboo it is really a design flaw to keep loading the same script over and over. Do some research into `event delegation` can do this once when page loads and not load other scripts again

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your feedback and help

Answer (score 1):

As other responses and comments said, the problem is that the pages you're loading via $.load() comes with her own javascript, with re-attach a listener to the page. So, the next time you try to load a page, its loaded by the original script and by the scripts loaded dinamically, too. Its not exactly a 'performance' problem, caused by loading contents with $.load() is slow or something, is a logic issue since your script is flawed by design, doing lots of things it shouldn't.

The solution is to load just the content you need to show without the javascript.

> Should i stop attaching one general javascript to all my external php files that i would load into? (split up the functions and save to multiple different js file? )

Well, I think the problem is not having a single javascript tied to your php scripts, but having a single php file with both the presentation data and the scripts links.   Should you have a php controller that loads the proper page with proper javascript, and then another set of proper php files with data to present (welcome, message, Face, Qr etc) and no redundant client-side scripting, you would have not this problem.

But, btw, separate your javascript into separate modules is a good decision too.

> Any other solution?

Well, you can detach the event listener as you load the new content,with $.off(), so listeners doesn't stack and extra content is not loaded with further requests. But is the kind of lazy approach that tend to be time-costly at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
$(".uk-navbar-nav").click(function(){
    if(!window['once']){
        window['once'] = true;

        //you code...

    }
});
```

Comment: Firstly, that code is very ugly. Secondly, it will make the `click` event work only once, and that's not the desired behavior.

Comment: It will not make the click event to work only once, it will make the code inside the if statement to be executed only once, and that is the desired behavior.

Comment: once for one element...then non of the others would work either